# OnClick Handler used for fetching data not working for a tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a few tabs and on clicking of those tabs, I want to fetch the data.

Here is the Sales Overview component:

```
class SalesOverview1 extends Component {
  state = {
    page_id: 4,
    hcp_id: 101,
    sales_overview_data: []
}


 salesOverviewClicked = () => {
    console.log('Clicked on sales Overview!');
    let page_id = this.state.page_id;
    let hcp_id = this.state.hcp_id;
    console.log('state: ', this.state);
    axios.post('/test-json', {
        page_id: page_id,
        hcp_id: hcp_id
    })
        .then((res) => {
            const dataRequest = res.data;
            console.log('State before loading data in sales overview: ', this.state);
            console.log('received data inside sales overview', res.data);
            this.setState({ ...this.state, sales_overview_data: res.data });
            console.log('State after loading data in sales overview: ', this.state);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}



return (
     <>
            <div role="tabpanel" id="tablet-3" class="tab-pane" onClick={this.salesOverviewClicked}>
                <div class="panel-body" style={{ backgroundColor: "rgb(243,243,244)", border: "none", 
                 margin: 0 }}>
     </>
      )
```

As you can see, I have added an onclick handler for the div but nothing is happening on clicking that tab. If I do onClick like this instead: onClick={this.salesOverviewClicked()} , I'm able to fetch the data but the data gets fetched repeatedly one after the other even if I don't click on it.

Just for perspective here is how the tabs look like:

[image]

I want to fetch the data only once after clicking on that tab. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You need `onClick={() => this.salesOverviewClicked()}` (your first attempt didn't bind `this`, which should've resulted in errors, your second attempt passed not a function but the result of the function call, which called your function each time the component was rendered)

Comment: Nothing is happening even then.

Comment: I didn't see you used `salesOverviewClicked = () => {`, which means it'll work without binding it explicitly. You should at the very least see the console logs; if you don't you need to create a [mre] for us to debug. On the other hand: navigating to a different pane should mount that respective pane; couldn't you simply run the code in the pane's componentDidMount() instead?

Comment: I checked the console log but I'm not even getting the message of 'Sales Overview Clicked!' which I have consoled log in the code. Don't know why the event handler isn't working.

Comment: In your JSX you're opening two divs. What's inside them? Try adding the click handler to an inner element. Still, this seems like the wrong approach in the first place. Detecting navigation should not require detecting a click on a tab label.

Comment: I've tried adding to the inner elements as well...

Comment: Did you try binding your event handler?  "onClick = this.salesOverviewClicked.bind(this)". Just give it a try.

Comment: Where should I write that? I tried writing like this but not working: onClick = {this.salesOverviewClicked.bind(this)}

Comment: Binding like that is not necessary here, and it has no effect on whether the click handler function is called or not. You need to provide a [mre] or we cannot help you.

Comment: I found the solution actually. I tried using the onClick event in another parent component which worked so no issues now. Thanks for trying to help! Basically, I wasn't passing the onClick event in the current location.

Comment: *correct location

Comment: I've asked a new question, you can check that if you want.